# How to use flat nested ternaries with ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have some code like this:

```
let upgrade;
if (device.firmwareV !== latestFirmware.version) {
    upgrade = "Firmware is up to date.";
} else if (!firmUpTool) {
    upgrade = "Cannot upgrade the firmware through this connection.";
} else if (latestFirmware.type !== device.type) {
    upgrade = "Cannot upgrade firmware of this device.";
} else {
    upgrade = upgradeControl(firmUpTool);
}
```

But I would prefer to use the ternary operator (condition `?` value1 `:` value2) because it allows me to replace `let` with `const` (and in my opinion it looks tidier, though I appreciate that opinions vary):

```
const upgrade =
    device.firmwareV !== latestFirmware.version ?
        "Firmware is up to date."
    : !firmUpTool ?
        "Cannot upgrade the firmware through this connection."
    : latestFirmware.type !== device.type ?
        "Cannot upgrade firmware of this device."
    : upgradeControl(firmUpTool);
```

But ESLint give 5 erros like `Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 8.`. If I follow the recommendations I have to indent the code even though I have given it an indent rule:

```
indent: [2, 4, {flatTernaryExpressions: true}]
```

I can get rid of the warnings by removing the newlines after each `?` but that makes lines excessively long and not as readable in my opinion.

Is there a better way of laying out flat nested ternaries or is there some other ESLint rule I should be using here?

Comment: why not use a function with early return? instead of chained `if .. else if ...` parts?

Comment: @Nina-Scholz Why not post that as an answer if you think it looks better.

Comment: I'd prefer the 1st one. Nested ternaries look ugly.

Comment: @hindmost In the past there have been few reasons to use nested ternaries, but now that `const` is preferred over `let` there is more incentive to code initialises as expressions. So with this question I am exploring whether it is time to embrace and learn to like what I also previously considered ugly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a fucntion which check the parts and return early if a condition is `true`.

The advantage is better readably and maintainability.

The missing `else` parts is covered by a possible earlier exit of the function.

```
function checkUpgrade() {
    if (device.firmwareV !== latestFirmware.version) {
        return "Firmware is up to date.";
    }
    if (!firmUpTool) {
        return "Cannot upgrade the firmware through this connection.";
    }
    if (latestFirmware.type !== device.type) {
        return "Cannot upgrade firmware of this device.";
    }
    return upgradeControl(firmUpTool);
}

const upgrade = checkUpgrade();
```

Comment: This is a good answer. It permits `const`. I have not marked it as the accepted answer because it does not directly address the ESLint question I asked.